# Suggestions for lightweight, thread-safe scheduler

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I am trying to write a round-robin scheduler for lightweight threads (fibers). It must scale to handle as many concurrently-scheduled fibers as possible. I also need to be able to schedule fibers from threads other than the one the run loop is on, and preferably unschedule them from arbitrary threads as well (though I could live with only being able to unschedule them from the run loop).

My current idea is to have a circular doubly-linked list, where each fiber is a node and the scheduler holds a reference to the current node. This is what I have so far:

```
using Interlocked = System.Threading.Interlocked;

public class Thread {
    internal Future current_fiber;

    public void RunLoop () {
        while (true) {
            var fiber = current_fiber;
            if (fiber == null) { 
                // block the thread until a fiber is scheduled
                continue;
            }
            if (fiber.Fulfilled)
                fiber.Unschedule ();
            else
                fiber.Resume ();

            //if (current_fiber == fiber) current_fiber = fiber.next;
            Interlocked.CompareExchange<Future> (ref current_fiber, fiber.next, fiber);      
        }
    }
}

public abstract class Future {
    public bool Fulfilled { get; protected set; }
    internal Future previous, next;

    // this must be thread-safe
    // it inserts this node before thread.current_fiber
    // (getting the exact position doesn't matter, as long as the
    //  chosen nodes haven't been unscheduled)
    public void Schedule (Thread thread) {
        next = this; // maintain circularity, even if this is the only node
        previous = this;
    try_again:
        var current = Interlocked.CompareExchange<Future> (ref thread.current_fiber, this, null);
        if (current == null)
            return;

        var target = current.previous;
        while (target == null) {
            // current was unscheduled; negotiate for new current_fiber
            var potential = current.next;
            var actual = Interlocked.CompareExchange<Future> (ref thread.current_fiber, potential, current);
            current = (actual == current? potential : actual);
            if (current == null)
                goto try_again;
            target = current.previous;
        }
        // I would lock "current" and "target" at this point.
        // How can I do this w/o risk of deadlock?
        next = current;
        previous = target;
        target.next = this;
        current.previous = this;
    }

    // this would ideally be thread-safe
    public void Unschedule () {
        var prev = previous;
        if (prev == null) {
            // already unscheduled
            return;
        }
        previous = null;
        if (next == this) {
            next = null;
            return;
        }
        // Again, I would lock "prev" and "next" here
        // How can I do this w/o risk of deadlock?            
        prev.next = next;
        next.previous = prev;
    }

    public abstract void Resume ();
}
```

As you can see, my sticking point is that I cannot ensure the order of locking, so I can't lock more than one node without risking deadlock. Or can I? I don't want to have a global lock on the Thread object, since the amount of lock contention would be extreme. Plus, I don't especially care about insertion position, so if I lock each node separately then Schedule() could use something like Monitor.TryEnter and just keep walking the list until it finds an unlocked node.

Overall, I'm not invested in any particular implementation, as long as it meets the requirements I've mentioned. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT -** The comments indicate that people think I'm talking about winapi fibers (which I'm not). In a nutshell, all I want to do is schedule bits of code to run one after the other on the **a single** thread. It is similar to the TPL / Async CTP, but AFIK those do not guarantee continuations on the same thread unless it happens to be the UI thread. I am open to alternate suggestions on how to implement the above, but please don't just say "don't use fibers."

Comment: what's wrong with the thread pool or a Backgroundworker?

Comment: I'm shooting for something cheaper than OS-level threads. I envision having tens of thousands (or more) fibers scheduling and unscheduling themselves

Comment: No offence, but for the Future I foresee annoyance, aggrevation, and failure. I've never even taken on the attempt to write fibers in winapi, and I suspect there's a suspioucely low amount of programmers and/or programs that ever did. Reason being that the amount of programs that fit the use case is around 0.000001% of all programs. (That, and I probably lack the technical knowledge).

Comment: No offense taken, but I think you misunderstand what I'm doing. I'm not trying to use winapi fibers, I'm creating a purely managed implementation (if I was using winapi I wouldn't need to implement the scheduler :) Eventually, this will become a core component of an RIA framework, which is a use case perfectly suited for fibers. In fact, all web apps are based on a run loop/scheduler somewhat like this- think setTimeout in javascript.

Comment: It looks like you're just re-implementing an event loop, not real lightweight threads.  How are your `Future`s different?

Comment: You might want to try the Actor pattern. The Magnum project https://github.com/phatboyg/Magnum has implemented it. The code is a bit involved and I too am trying to get my head wrapped around it

Comment: @Karmastan I AM trying to implement an event loop. It is not a "real" lightweight thread, just a framework-level construct.
@Hakeem Yes! That project looks interesting, I'll check it out.

Comment: You seem to be attempting to write something that is essentially useless. Gains from parallelising come from getting the granularity right. 10,000 of 'lightweight fibres' is not the right granularity.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Task Parallel Library.

Create a custom `TaskScheduler` as shown on MSDN.  In your custom task scheduler, if you want just one thread you can have just one thread.

If you want to prevent it from scheduling tasks inline, override `protected override bool TryExecuteTaskInline(Task task, bool taskWasPreviouslyQueued)` and return `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Fibers with .NET, read anything by Joe Duffy on this subject.  Use the TPL instead for a correct implementation of a user-mode scheduler.

Comment: I am not using winapi fibers. I edited my question to make it a little clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that running on a single thread is not required, only that one task at a time runs to completion. If this is the case, download the [TPL samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ParExtSamples/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4179). Look into using the LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler with a MaximumConcurrency of 1.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a simple [lock-free message queue](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/lockfreeq.aspx) to queue your Futures.

Rather than keeping a cyclic datastructure, you pull the Future off the queue before calling  Resume(), and have it appended when completed (if there is more work to do).